# HTML button does not show the same functionality when clicking with VBA opposed to when clicking manually

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, dialog

Manually:

1. Open IE
2. Open URL
3. Click HTML Button (Button1 for sake of argument)
4. Click OK on the pop-up Dialogue Wait for client to contact server and then Excel sheet opens.

By VBA (my code currently does this):

1. Open IE Open URL
2. Click HTML Button (Button1 for sake of argument)

This all works fine and the pop-up dialogue appears the same as it does when manually clicking Button1. However at this point when i manually click the OK button on the dialogue nothing happens!

I can't see what the difference is because the last action in both sequences is the same (a manual press on the OK button of the dialogue).

Has anyone seen this type of issue before?

Edit:

Thanks for your help so far guys, i should have mentioned i'm attmepting to interact with HTML on a Sharepoint server. Below is my code and the html source. I know that my method of finding the button is probably not the strongest or most standard but it was the only thing i could use as a search param at the time.

My VBA:

```
'------------------------------- Open IE & URL
    Dim appIE As Object
    Dim URL As String

    URL = "http://OurSharePointServer/epr/default.aspx"
    Set appIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With appIE
        .navigate URL
        .Visible = True
    End With

    While appIE.Busy Or appIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend
'---------------------------------------------

'------------------------------- Click "Raise New EPR" Button
    For Each htma In appIE.document.getElementsByTagName("img")
   '     Debug.Print htma.onclick
        If InStr(htma.onclick, "createNewDocumentWithProgID") > 0 Then
            Dim appExcel As Object
            Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
            appExcel.Workbooks.Add
            htma.Click
            Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
'---------------------------------------------
```

The HTML source of the button:

```
<IMG 
onclick="createNewDocumentWithProgID('http:\u002f\u002fOurSharepointServer\u002fepr\u002fsubmit\u002fForms\u002fepr_.xls',    
'http:\u002f\u002fOurIntranet\u002fepr\u002fsubmit',    
'SharePoint.OpenDocuments', false)" 
src="../site%20images/epr_but.jpg" 
<a href="http://OurSharepointServer/epr/Submit">
```

Comment: Difficult to answer without a URL or the relevant HTML source, and your existing VBA.

Comment: Added additional information :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified nothing more, the only clue is to apply `.focus()` method to that <kbd>HTML Button (Button1 for sake of argument)</kbd> just before `.click()`, and also applying `.blur()` method for other elements on the page you are interacting with might help. Generally it might be a handler assigned to one of these events, which finally results in such behavior difference.